# AttributeError: 'GameWidget' object has no attribute '_on_keyboard_close'

Tags: python, kivy

After I am writing code to build a game. I am getting this error. How can I fix this? I am really confused about it. I am new in kivy. This is the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 44, in <module>
    app.run()
  line 829, in run
    root = self.build()
  line 39, in build
    return GameWidget()
  line 10, in __init__
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._on_keyboard_close, self)
AttributeError: 'GameWidget' object has no attribute '_on_keyboard_close'
```

My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window

class GameWidget(Widget):
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
   super().__init__(**kwargs)
   self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._on_keyboard_close, self)
   self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)

with self.canvas:
   self.player = Rectangle(source="hero.bmp", pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 100))

def _on_keyboard_closed(self):
   self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
   self._keyboard = none

def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
   currentx = self.player.pos[0]
   currenty = self.player.pos[1]
   newx = currentx
   newy = currenty

   if text == "w":
       currenty += 1
   if text == "s":
        currenty -= 1
   if text =="a":
        currentx -= 1
   if text =="d":
        currentx += 1

   self.player.pos = (newx, newy)

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return GameWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = MyApp()
   app.run()
```

I really appreciate if you see and help to solve this problem.

Comment: You defined the method `_on_keyboard_closed` but call it as `self._on_keyboard_close`. Mind the `d` in the end

Comment: @mohammad khoshanazar, the 'errors' you are getting is actually just one error. The 3 lines are a Traceback showing you the entire path of where the error originated from..

Answer (score 1):

Here, the problem is **_on_keyboard_close** isn't getting detected as you have called the function as _on_keyboard_close while you have defined the function as *_on_keyboard_close**d***. You just got a spelling mistake.

> ```
> self._on_keyboard_close 
> def _on_keyboard_closed(self):
> ```